# The bare minimum of Implementing and using IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm mimicking .NET's session, with some minor differences (my class has only pre-defined fields - either strings or ints..).
I have read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=VS.100).aspx) and some SO posts about implementing IDisposable, but it seems too much..
My event handler for the timer's Elapsed event calls a static method that should dispose the object sent to it.

Like so:

```
        public APISession()
        {
            timer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler(disposeSession);
            timer.Start();
        }
        private static void disposeSession(object obj,ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        { 
             //Should dispose APISession here (not obj - which is the timer, 
             //but rather -this)
        } 
        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

**Added:** This is APISession's declaration:

```
class APISession:IDisposable
```

Can someone please tell me how to dispose the current APISession object?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about _implementing_ IDisposable for your Seesion class or how to _call_ Dispose() in the Timer? Your code points both ways.

Comment: @Henk: Good point- I'm asking about both. I'll change the wording.

Comment: You do realize the 'received' object is a timer?

Comment: @leppie: Very good point.. Sorry. Changed the naming..

Answer (score 2):

If you only use the object inside the disposeSession method, you have to dispose of it there. Only class variables should be disposed by implementing IDisposable.

At the end of disposeSession method, add the folloing code to dispose of it, if it implements IDisposable.

```
if(toDispose is IDisposable)
  (toDispose as IDisposable).Dispose();
```

or you can write it like this

```
IDisposable disposable = toDispose as IDisposable;
if( disposable != null )
  disposable.Dispose();
```

**edit**
Added a cast as corrected by the comments, and added the version using as and checking for null

Comment: I'd suggest that you use the AS statement to get an IDisposable interface and call dispose on that

Comment: yes, IDisposable disposable = toDispose as IDisposable; if (disposable != null) {disposable.Dispose();}

Comment: @Øyvind: read up on the `as` cast – your current code does redundant work. *Always* use the idiom posted by @vc74 instead.

Comment: Actually, this will dispose the timer, in case no one noticed.  :)